# Connecting a deployed flask app to database that's hosted on another server/provider

Tags: python, mysql, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Pretty much I would like to know or be pointed in the right direction on how to connect a deployed flask application to a mysql db that's hosted on another server/database. I'll either be deploying with PythonAnywhere or Linode, but don't know how I would go about connecting it to the database that's hosted on another linux server. I do have access to this server, I was given the ssh credentials and ip. Do I need to create an ssh tunnel through my hosted application? I'm a noob and have never deployed a flask application before so I'm especially shaky on deploying and connecting it to a db that's already deployed as well. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Good chance you are using the declaritive engine where you define your DB.

A common way is to set (password sensitive) variables such as database URL's in the environment.

```sh
export DB_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/database
```

Modify this URL to your target host and make sure this host accepts incoming connections.
In your app you can refer to this:

```py
import os
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine(os.getenv('DB_URL'))
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                         autoflush=False,
                                         bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
```

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/sqlalchemy/